# Lambda to compare two Lists

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have 3 lists of type `cab`.  I need to Compare  `listA` and `listB`.  If the `Car-number` or `status` in `listB` is the same as that in `listA` then I have to add that row in `listB` to `listC' else add it to`listA`.  I need to perform that same operation for all rows for`listB`.  How do I write a lambda on two lists to perform this?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
public class cab
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Desc {get;set;}
    public int Car_number   {get;set;}
    public bool status {get;set;}

}
cab c1 = new cab() { Name = "Zen",Desc = "äsdasdf",Car_number= "8832",status="false"};
cab c2 = new cab() { Name = "Ford",Desc = "sdfgedasdf",Car_number= "1132",status="true"};
cab c3 = new cab() { Name = "Swift",Desc = "sdsdf",Car_number= "732",status="true"};

List<cab> listA = new List<cab>();

listA.Add(c1);
listA.Add(c2);
listA.Add(c3);


List<cab> listB  = new List<cab>();
cab c4 = new cab() { Name = "Santro",Desc = "iisdasdf",Car_number= "8832",status="false"};
cab c5 = new cab() { Name = "Ritz",Desc = "esddf",Car_number= "132",status="true"};

listB.Add(c4);
listB.Add(c5);
List<cab> listC  = new List<cab>();
```

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you used a more traditional iterative approach?  You should at least start there if you're just learning LINQ, even if you hope to have a LINQ solution at some point.

Comment: would be useful to at least get the data type right:
`Car_number= "8832"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any specific reason for a need for lambda?

Would this work for you?

```
foreach (var bItem in listB)
{
    if (listA.Any(aItem => bItem.Car_number == aItem.Car_number || bItem.status == aItem.status))
        listC.Add(bItem);
    else
        listA.Add(bItem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
listB.ForEach(b =>
   {
      if (listA.Any(a => a.Car_number == b.Car_number || a.status == b.status))
      {
         listC.Add(b);
      }
      else
      {
         listA.Add(b);
      }
   }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want actually the lambda expression, Try this:

```
    public static void ChoiseAndAdd(Cab cab,ref List<Cab> listA,ref List<Cab> listC)
    {
        if (listA.Any(e => e.Car_number == cab.Car_number) || listA.Any(e => e.status == cab.status))
        {
            listC.Add(cab);
            return;
        }
        listA.Add(user);
    }
```

and the expression:

```
listB.ForEach(e => ChoiseAndAdd(e, ref listA, ref listC));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Populate list C
listC = listA.Where(a=>  listB.Select(b=>b.Car_number).Contains(a.Car_number) && listB.Select(b => b.status).Contains(a.status)).ToList();
//Populate ListB using ListC
listB.AddRange(listA.Where(a => ! listC.Select(c => c.Car_number).Contains(a.Car_number) && ! listC.Select(c => c.status).Contains(a.status)).ToList());
```

Note: I stumbled upon here with a similar issue and clarified my doubt using your code. I know that this is an old question and an answer has already been provided (and accepted). But I thought I'd post the above solution for others who might come here looking for an answer.